# to get data from a method in controller and display it in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, get

I have written a method to count the vote for particular section and to display it in view file for section. But when I call this method count is not incremented. Should i make any changes in following method

code for voteme method in controller is as:

```
     def voteme(num)
         @section = Section.find(params[:id])
         @section.vote += num
     end
```

and code in view file is

<%= link_to "up", :url => voteme_section_path(1), :html => { :method => :post }%>

also can anyone suggest me the code to display updated count value.I have a vote field in section model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file

```
<%= link_to "up", voteme_section_path(1), :method => :post %>
```

But I have a question, you are voting up against a section. So why you are passing 1 to it. you should pass the section object if you would have stored it in @section variable. So its better you can modify the link as

```
<%= link_to "up", voteme_section_path(@section), :method => :post %>
```

In your route file I guess you need to do some thing like this

```
resources :sections do
  member do
    post 'voteme'
  end
end
```

And in the sections controller, 'voteme' action

```
def voteme
  @section = Section.find_by_id(params[:id])

  unless @section.blank?
    @section.update_column('vote', @section.vote + 1)
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Sorry something goes wrong'
  end

  redirect_to your-path-that-you want-to-show.
end
```

Comment: thanks its working. I have changed the methods "find_by_id" to "find" and "update_column" to "update_attribute".

Comment: Thats great. in case you will give some id which is not there in the sections table, then "find" will raise an error but find_by_id returns nil which can be handled easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @section.save after you change the value.

This logic should also be in the model, rather than in the controller. The controller should only pass things back and forth between the model and the view.

Comment: thanks to both of u but vote value is not updated when i clicked on up. getting same value 0

Answer (score 0):

```
def voteme(num)
  @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  @section.update_attribute('vote', @section.vote+1)
end
```